# Network HDD Spins-up on PC Startup

Tags: windows, hard-drive, samba, spinup

I have a Asus router connected to and external HDD that I use as a Network drive (using built-in SMB, samba).  I have the network location mapped to my windows PC. Currently, when I start up my pc, that network drive will also spin-up even though I am not browsing the files through explorer or some other means.  Is there a way (besides for unmounting the network drive) to not have the network drive spin up when not accessing it?

Comment: Actually the external HDD is waking up  because of the Windows is attempt to read from it. Therefore the question is “WHY the Windows is  trying to read from  the external HDD?” Perhaps you are created the network sharing on it and the Windows is trying to probe it.